# Как правильно использовать from_object во Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Есть некоторое приложение со следующей структурой

```
notes
.../notes
   ..../__init__.py
   ..../config.py
.../run.py
```

Внутри `config.py`:

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config:
    DEBUG = False
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    SECRET_KEY = '2222222222222222'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    DEVELOPMENT = False


class DevelopConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
```

В `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.DevelopConfig')
```

Файл `run.py:`:

```
from notes import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Немного не понимаю в чем ошибка, наверняка что-то делаю не так со структурой. Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Навскидку, надо `notes.config.DevelopConfig`, как импортируется, также и писать...

Comment: @mrEvgenX Спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесу ответ [@mrEvgenX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/271103/mrevgenx) из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210054/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-from-object-%d0%b2%d0%be-flask#comment2114540_1210054)

В вызове функции `from_object` нужно указывать полный путь импорта объекта. [В документации Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-files) в примерах указан самый простой способ импорта, так как подразумевается, что модуль с конфигурацией расположен непосредственно рядом с модулем приложения. В вашем же случае, модуль конфигурации находится внутри пакета `notes`, в связи с чем в определении импорта объекта нужно указать `notes.config.DevelopConfig`:

```py
# __init__.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('notes.config.DevelopConfig')
```